# Is it natural to say "You think it's going that bad"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: I think I'm just gonna go.

B: **You think it's going that bad, huh?**

A: Yes, I do.

I tried searching "You think it's going that bad" on Google but it had no hits. Is it not natural at all?

Comment: Context please?

Comment: Two friends who have fallen out with each other meet to talk things over but end up in another argument.

Comment: @user11826 It sounds to me like the conversation _went bad(ly)_. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Agree that "it's going badly" is best, because that describes pretty much any process which is proceeding towards failure, with the adverb "badly" modifying the verb "going."

"It's going bad" implies that a particular item, especially food, is becoming inedible.

Answer (score 0):

It’s generally acceptable, especially in speech, but does have a bit of a slang vibe to it; it would sound more proper to say “badly”. Notice that “going that  good” also doesn’t sound right, and should be “going that well”.

If you just google “going that bad” you should see a lot more results and get a good idea of when this would be used, but it is fine in your example/context.